# R Studio crashing not at initialization. Error: Error occurred during transmission

Tags: r, docker, rstudio, rstudio-server

Some context on my environment:

I am running R Studio in a docker container called [rocker/verse](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/verse).
I downloaded [this dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/ntnu-testimon/paysim1/download) from Kaggle, which has about 470 MB.

When working with it, at some point RStudio restart. It does't happen after a specific call, and I've seen the same problem when working with other projects. Though it is not related to my code, I am posting it bellow.

```
library(data.table)
fraud<- fread("path.csv")
fraud1<- sort(sample(nrow(fraud), nrow(fraud)*.7))
train<- fraud[fraud1, ]
test<-fraud[-fraud1, ]
```

Usually on the console this message is printed:

> Error: Error occurred during transmission

And, this pop up is also showed:

[image: R Session Error]

I have no idea what is causing it. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `.Rhistory` files associated with the installation and any open project.

Comment: Trying removing .Rhistory, remove .config/rstudio .local/share/rstudio all failed to eliminate the problem. This problem happened to me after migrating R from 4.0 to 4.2

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your user data files for Rstudio. Follow the hints given here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-server-error-occurred-during-transmission/84258 and here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-RStudio-Server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.